# How do I convert my 3D model into a 2D texture image?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I may just be being stupid here and missed something, but I'm having a problem with something. I have a model for something I made and am going to make it into a mesh, though the colors don't transfer so of course I have to make it into a texture. the only problem is I have no idea how to. I basically want the model and colors separate so I can add it later back on. If you need to know, I'm trying to do this for Roblox. I have seen someone with the same question but the answer was honestly just too much tech talk for me to understand.
Yes, I'm dumb, But I hope to get better at this over time.

Comment: Are you able to give us a screenshot or test files? I want to know how did you put colours on the model? Did you use only materials or did you paint the model?

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely easy.

Just select your object, switch the render engine to Cycles, and bake the textures from here:

[image]

[image]

You can play with the options to get your desired result. You can bake your colour texture (named diffuse in the dropdown), the emission (Emit), the Roughness, the Normals, and a long list of more texture maps. You can also control if the scene lights affect our textures or not from the influence section, and which texture maps also. Then after modifying the settings to what you want, (remember that you also have output settings!) press the Bake button and tada! (Ignore the selected to active for now). Also, remember to open a image editor window so you can save your file from there:

[image]